# Why can't I store a UserID (users.get_current_user()) in a Session variable in Python in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to store a UserID in a session variable in Google App Engine (Python).

The session variable functionality works fine.  In fact, I can even store the key in a session.  This works:

```
    self.session['Xuser'] = user.key.id()
```

This does not work:

```
    self.session['Xuser'] = users.get_current_user()
```

I even tried tricking the system by putting the UserID into another variable first.  This also does not work:

```
    tempcode = users.get_current_user()
    self.session['Xuser'] = tempcode
```

The problem is solely with the 2nd line when I try to put the UserID into the session variable.  Can anyone tell me why and what I need to do to be able to store the UserID in a session variable in such a way that I can compare it

I need to do this because I have a UserSupplement kind and I don't want a user to be able to put more than one entry into this kind for the same UserID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
self.session['Xuser'] = users.get_current_user().user_id()
```

Answer (score 1):

All objects that you want to store in session must be serializable. `User` obviously isn't.